# facebook website likes shows k instead of the specific number

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My Facebook website like button shows 2.5k instead of the actual number of likes. How can I change this to  display the specific number please.

The coding in the header used is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

The coding for the page is:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.nuborns.co.uk/photography" data-send="false"   data-layout="button_count" data-width="400" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make your like box bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Hello sherie deen: k = 1000, you should set bigger the button width.
Hope it helps